# Add text to powerpoint slide using vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have PowerPoint with a slide master set so all slides have same characteristics. I want to use VBA to place the SlideIndex number of the corresponding slide on each side.

As of now I have it so when you click a button, the slide index pops up in a message box but I want it to pop up in a text box or something on the slide itself.

Here is  the script I am currently using..

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

    MsgBox SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex

End Sub
```

I do not want to use a button. I want to automatically have it on each slide when its ran..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a text box to one slide.  While it's selected, type this in the Immediate window to name it something meaningful to you:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "SlideNumber"
```

Then your button handling code can look like:

```
With SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex.Shapes("SlideNumber")
   .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cstr(SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex)
End with
```

Comment: What if I dont want to use a button. I want to it automatically post the pageIndex when opened

Comment: Then you need to set up an event handler and trap the appropriate event and respond to it, and that pretty much has to live in an add-in.  It gets LOTS more complex.  Alternatively, you can run the presentation in kiosk mode and add your own "Next" and "Previous" buttons.  The "Next" button can add the slide number and then advance to the next slide.

Comment: I would like to make an add-in...  How would this look in an add-in? OnPresentationOpen() ?

Comment: Have a look at this article on the PowerPoint FAQ site that I maintain (there's also a link there to another article about handling events).  How can I get my code to run automatically when a presentation opens?
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00741_How_can_I_get_my_code_to_run_automatically_when_a_presentation_opens-.htm

Comment: What do you mean " type this is in the Immediate window to name it something meaningful"?

Comment: Press Alt+F11 to get into the Visual Basic editor (also called the Integrated Development Environment or IDE).  Press Ctrl + G to open the Immediate window.  You can type VBA commands directly into this window ... press Enter and they're executed immediately.  Hence its name.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you don't need VBA for this.

Go to the slide master view.  On the master, add a text box wherever you want the slide index to appear.

While you have the text insertion cursor active, choose:  Insert | Slide Number